# java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation: [6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I am using version Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production Version 21.3.0.0.0
I am linking to remote database. But when I query the table I get the error "Protocol Violation"

> java.sql.SQLException: Protocol Violation: [ 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, ] at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:755) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:291) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:492) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:108) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.fetch(T4CStatement.java:1159) at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.fetchMoreRows(OracleStatement.java:3759) at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.fetchMoreRows(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:821) at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.fetchNextRows(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:759) at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.absoluteInternal(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:731) at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.next(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:436) in RemoteResultSetImpl.getObjects(RemoteResultSetImpl.java:1342)

I think the error is caused by jdbc drivers. Can you help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDZ8G.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE].

Comment: Which version of the Oracle JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: Sql Developer is using ojdbc8.jar. My sql developer version: 21.4.3.063.0100-x64

Comment: ojdbc8 is not a version, it just means it is for Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue myself, and while I don't have a clear understanding of *exactly* what's going wrong here, I was able to identify that this happens when the JDBC driver receives a value from a VARCHAR2 column (because that column is included in the SELECT) that meets certain characteristics (unclear what those characteristics are), and for whatever reason the driver isn't able to figure out what to do with the bytes that it receives over the TCP connection and throws this exception. I'm working with Japanese-language data in a fairly old database, which may be contributing to the weirdness (and the setup is using Oracle's database link functionality, which also might be a relevant factor - perhaps a character encoding mismatch between the local database and the remote database). This seems to happen regardless of driver version (I encountered it both with 12.2.0.1 and 23.2.0.0).

There may be a more elegant solution, but I hacked around this by writing my SELECT in the following way:

```
SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN COLUMN_NAME IS NULL THEN NULL
    ELSE utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(COLUMN_NAME)))
    END AS COLUMN_NAME_BASE64
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

This got me the bytes as a base64 string, which can be trivially converted to a string of unicode characters in the Java program (and if there exist a subset of values for which that conversion fails for whatever reason, you can just catch that exception in the Java program and handle it as you like).